# Shining progressbar in java swing application

Tags: java, swing

Can anyone have shining progressbar component for java swing application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a different progress bar, but rather a different *look* for the progress bar.

The look of Swing widgets is determined by the **Pluggable Look&Feel** (PLAF), so you just have to find a PLAF that renders the progress bar with a glossy/shiny style.

A selection of PLAFs can be found here:
[Best Java Swing Look and Feel Themes | Top 10](http://www.taranfx.com/best-java-swing-look-and-feel-themes-professional-casual-top-10)

If none of those fulfill your needs, it's quite easy to subclass an existing PLAF and exchange for example only the **ProgressBarUI**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a different lookAndFeel: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html